# PHP единая точка входа?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, делаю единую точку входа(подключаю страницы) и не могу реализовать такое.
Имею вот такой код в файле index.php

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ) {

    include 'html/main.inc.php';

} else {

    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $pg = explode('?', $page, 2);

    if ( file_exists('html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php') ) {

    include 'html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php';

        } else {

        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != 'html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php') {

            include "html/error.inc.php";

        }
    }

}
```

И я подключаю файлы этим кодом

```
if ( file_exists('html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php') ) {

    include 'html/'.$pg['0'].'.inc.php';
```

но открывает страницы такого вида site.ru/login

а я хочу чтоб открывалось с каталога например site.ru/account/login

Comment: Сделайте замену `/` на `.` и по `site.ru/account/login` будет открывать файл `html/account.login.inc.php`.

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) на будущее вам в помощь